# ClaimTypes for getting the user's profile image in mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth

This is my `ExternalLoginConfirmation` task, that is the default code added when the project is created. I have added these lines to get the user claims:

```
user.Firstname = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.ToString();
user.Lastname = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.ToString();
user.Gender = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Gender)?.ToString();
```

However  I'm not able to get the user profile image as it does not exist in `ClaimTypes`.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    user.Firstname = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.ToString();
                    user.Lastname = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.ToString();
                    user.Gender = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Gender)?.ToString();

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    _logger.LogInformation(6, "User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Note that `info` is missing `ExternalPrincipal` and the following functionality is not available either:

```
info.ExternalPrincipal.FindFirstValue("pictureUrl");
```

Comment: Ever found an answer for this?

Comment: @Diomedes google has stopped providing profile image like this and you should enable google plus api, and request the profile picture using the provided api key. I'm adding the solution I'm using in a minute. just check the answer

Comment: @Diomedes I added the answer (copied from my own project). I just get the image link and add it to my database you may want to modify it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the soultion I'm using now:

```
 var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
       if (result.Succeeded)
       {
            result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                 if (info.LoginProvider.ToLower().IndexOf("google") != -1)
                    { await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("GooglePlusId", info.ProviderKey));
                        try {
                                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                                HttpResponseMessage x = await client.GetAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{info.ProviderKey}?fields=image&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_API_KEY");
                               dynamic img = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await x.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                                user.PhotoLink = img.image.url;
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            catch { }

                    }

                        if (info.LoginProvider.ToLower().IndexOf("facebook") != -1)
                        {
                            user.PhotoLink = $"http://graph.facebook.com/{info.ProviderKey}/picture?type=square&width=50";
                        }   
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        _logger.LogInformation(6, "User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
```

P.S.: this code should be added to `ExternalLoginConfirmation` action in `AccountControllers` controller